# laravel 5, where clause with multiple values

Tags: laravel, where-clause

I wanted to pass all $id values to the where clause, 3rd line from the code below. but as i'am trying to return $friend it is null. am i addressing the $id values incorrectly? or i got it wrong in the query? i checked my database and it should return 2 rows.

i also checked $id by returning it and it returns what i am expecting and i guess i got it wrong in the query in $friend line.

```
$x = user->id;  

$id = DB::table('requests')->select('id')->where('id', '=', $x)->get();

$friend = DB::table('users')->where('id', 'in', $id)->get();
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use `whereIn()`, and maybe a better option for the whole deal would be:

```
$ids = DB::table('requests')->where('id', $x)->lists('id');
$friend = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

Note that the second parameter of whereIn() needs to be an array.

Comment: thnx dude. this really helped me.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is [`whereIn`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses) (scroll down a bit). It's also possible to use `whereNotIn`.

```
$userIds = [1, 2, 3];
$friend = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', $userIds)->get();
```

Or `whereNotIn`:

```
$userIds = [1, 2, 3];
$friend = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', $userIds)->get();
```

Take a look at all the possible advanced where clauses which are supported by the Laravel query builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in a single query:

```php
$friends = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', function ($query) use ($user) {
    $query->select('id')->from('requests')->where('id', $user->id);
})->get();
```

Comment: I believe that's still 2 queries, just nested.

Comment: @YasenSlavov - Nope. It's a subquery: `select * from users where id in (select id from requests where id = ?)`

Comment: That's what I meant. But they're still considered separate queries performance-wise.

Comment: Nope. There's a *huge* difference. This is a single trip to the database.